# How to determine if $\sum \frac{(n-\ln(n))^n}{2^n \cdot n^n}$ converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, proof-verification, limits-without-lhopital

$$\sum \frac{(n-\ln(n))^n}{2^n \cdot n^n}$$

$$u_{n}= \frac{(n-\ln(n))^n}{2^n \cdot n^n}$$

$$\Rightarrow (u_n)^{1/n} = \frac{n- \ln(n)}{2\cdot n } = \frac12\cdot (1 - \frac{\ln(n)}{n}) \to \frac12 \cdot(1-0) = \frac12 \;\; as \; n \to \infty$$

Hence convergent by root test.

Is this proof fine?

Comment: looks fine to me

Comment: You mean the $n^\text{th}$ root test?  Looks good.

Comment: @KajHansen yes. edited it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is correct. You may also say that
$$0<\frac{(n-\ln(n))^n}{2^n \cdot n^n}=\frac{(1-\frac{\ln(n)}{n})^n}{2^n}\leq \frac{1}{2^n}$$
and use the [comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_comparison_test).